# Android studio not connecting to virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-emulator

When I start my app in Android Studio, as usual, the emulator starts and the app openes.

But:

1. After I start the app, the run-logo doesn't change to the reload-logo.
2. When clicking the non-changed logo again, I can see "Install successfully finished in 1 s 451 ms." in "Run", but the app doesn't restart.
3. System.out and Log.e don't work

I tried:

1. Restarting Android Studio
2. Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. Rebuilding gradle
4. Wiping the emulator data
5. Reinstalling the app
6. Resetting the Run/Debug configurations

I found a question to another app starting problem, the answer was telling to delete the .AndroidStudio folder, but I could not find it (searched on my whole computer)

My theory:
Android Studio is just starting my emulator and the app, but has no connection to it, as if I would start the app by myself.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation yet, so I will ask my questions here.

Did you try to remove your virtual device and install a different virtual device ?

if that doesn't work, then maybe you should try to create a new project and check if it runs, just to make sure it's not a problem of your current project.

if the new project is working then try to move all of your code to the new project and check if it's working there.

Comment: I really don't know why, but it works on a new device. I thought that every piece of data would be deleted when using "wipe data". I feared creating a new project, because the app is already uploaded in the PlayStore and I just wanted to update it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

I also had similiar problem, installing a different virtual device helped me there.