# Android Studio stuck 'Connecting to emulator'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I recently updated Android studio, and as usual, it broke. Whenever I try to launch an emulator, Android Studio gets stuck in the 'Connecting to emulator' screen forever.

Things I've tried:

- Increasing VM heap size to 512mb
- Decreasing RAM size to 512mb
- Wiping device data
- Invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio
- Changing the device's system image (to API 32 arm64-v8a)
- Reinstalling the virtual device
- Installing a new virtual device

I'm on an M1 Macbook and running Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3

edit: I've also tried switching to Cold Boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio not connecting to virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66742901/android-studio-not-connecting-to-virtual-device)

Comment: My problem was solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70891877/3798

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by reinstalling Android Studio and the emulator.

Answer (score 42):

I fixed my issue using the following steps:

**Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator -> Uncheck “Launch in a tool window”.**

And retry to launch emulator again OR run app on using the same emulator.

Comment: Thank YOU!! Only this helped me with my Android Automotive OS emulator.

Comment: Dude, thank you! I had this problem when i upgraded my ionic app to capacitor 4.

Comment: Can you explain why this fix the issue ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 2021.3.1 Patch 1 :(. Wiping the user data fixes the issue but everytime I close the AVD it gets stuck again and I have to wipe again, horrible bug

Answer (score 11):

## Solution1

1. Stop Emulator from AVD Manager
2. From Android Studio, select “Tools” > “Android” > AVD Manager.
3. Right-click the emulator you are using, then choose “Stop“.
4. Try running the emulator again.

## Solution 2 – Exit Docker (MacOS)

Exit out of the Docker application on your Mac computer, then attempt to launch the emulator again.

## Solution 3 – Wipe Image

1. From Android Studio, select “Tools” > “Android” > AVD Manager.
2. Right-click the emulator you are using, then choose “Wipe Data“.
3. Try running the emulator again.

## Solution 4 – Uninstall and Reinstall AVD

1. From Android Studio, select “Tools” > “SDK Manager” > “SDK Tools“.
2. Uncheck “Android Emulator“.
3. Select “Apply” to have the emulator uninstalled.
4. Once the emulator has been removed, check the “Android Emulator” box again, then select “Apply” to reinstall it.

## Solution 5 - Coldboot

1. Go to Device Manager.
2. Right-click your virtual device.
3. Select Cold Boot Now.

## Extra

1. Make use of Android Studio’s ‘Instant Run’
2. Install HAXM and Switch to x86. …
3. Virtual machine acceleration. …
4. Disable the emulator’s boot animation.
5. Free your ram by closing unnecessary apps.

Comment: cold boot what the solution for me

Comment: I'm glad it resolved your issue @OmarZaoujal

Comment: wipe data worked for me

Answer (score 8):

This help me

Go to `Device Manager` and right-click your virtual device and select `Cold Boot Now`

Or you can make new virtual device

Answer (score 3):

For me helped to enable checkbox "Enable device frame" in avd config.

Comment: stupid bug, works for me :)

Comment: Tried this because it was one of the easiest things suggested, and, surprisingly, it worked!

Comment: Works for me too.

I'm using Android Studio Dolphin and the error is only with tablet emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio Hedgehog: in the Device Manager select the device - right menu: Wipe Data then Cold Boot.

Answer (score 0):

Me Problem Solve By creating new Virtual device by changing from `Quick boot` to `Cold boot`.

"In quick boot emulator start from stat that saved when the device last exited"

"while Cold boot emulator start as from a power up"

[how to change from QUICK BOOT to COLD BOOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwuRL.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a **flutter** project, run from the terminal `flutter doctor`. In my case, it reported that the SDK was not properly set up for flutter.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to connect by using the "1:1" view when displayed in the tool window.
Once it is displayed, you can resize window size.

Steps:

1. [Connecting to Emulator] prompt shown
2. Click [1:1] button

The environment is as follows

- MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
- Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- Android Emulator 31.3.14
- Android Tiramisu arm64-v8a

Answer (score 0):

for my case I made a new virtual device to crank or stop the "AVD still running" error. [The "Pixel 2 API" is the new virtual device I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8moZ.png) because I can't delete, cold boot, and wipe data the "Test HP General" virtual device from "AVD still running" error.

Then, I checked out what should I do with that error and found out you have to uninstall the IDE. But, I don't really want to uninstall the AVD because from other case when I reinstall the AVD I got many problem that makes me have to reset my PC. Because my AMD emulator got bricked.

In short, from making another Virtual Device and run it. The AVD would restart and make the error and booting problem go away.

If this doesn't help, then you should try to do it manually by going to the AVD file section and try to stop it from running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

wiping user data fixed the issue on my side,