# Waiting for all target devices to come online in Android studio imulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I tried to wipe data and cool boot ways in Android studio imulator before running the app. But this app shows imulator opened but app not running in that imulator and showing that waiting for all target devices to come online
I attached image also so anyone please solve this problem.[following there is the image please answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dclYQ.jpg)

When I am running and studio project this is happening which I shown in above image so please anyone can solve that problem

Comment: Try this solution it worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74026977/7269017

Answer (score 0):

open the **Device Manager** and click on **3 dots** in "**Action**" and select **Show on Disk** option.
it opens the file manager and show emulator data and Delete **hardware-qemu.ini.lock** file and **multiinstance** Lock file.
Then restart android studio now open the **Device Manager** and click on **3 dots** in "**Action**" and select **Wipe Data** then run the device.

Comment: I completed the process which you said but not working still showing waiting for all target devices to come online and device opened but not opening app.

Answer (score 0):

Click on **File** >> **Invalidate cache...**
then run app.